# Finding the textNode which the cursor is currently over

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following...

`<div id="text">Some text</div>`

When my mouse goes over `Some`, `Some` will be returned and the same with `text`.

Is this possible without putting each node into it's own element?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much impossible. Since in `Javascript` you just know that you are hovering over an `element` (`div` and/or a `textnode` in this case), you can't know which word is hovered just like that.

Maybe with alot of effort and some geeky hacks on `offsets` and/or `event.pageX/Y`, but I would go for the solution you mentioned yourself, wrapping each word into its own `element`.

```
var $text = $('#text');
$text.html($text.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span class='word'>$1</span>"));

$('.word').bind('mouseenter', function(e){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without either wrapping the two nodes in elements or somehow determining the exact position of the text nodes and then binding to some parent's `click` event. The former option is simpler. Just wrap them in spans:

```
<div id="text"><span>Some<span> <span>text</span></div>
```

Or, if you need to wrap them all automatically:

```
jQuery.fn.getTextNodes = function(){
    return this.not('script').contents().map(function(){
        var n = this.nodeType;
        return n === 3 ? this : n === 1 ? jQuery(this).getTextNodes().get() : [];
    });
};

jQuery('#text').getTextNodes().replaceWith(function(){
    return jQuery(this.data.replace(/\S+/g, '<span>$&</span>')).filter('span').click(function(){
        alert('You just clicked on the word: ' + jQuery.text([this]));
    }).end();
});​ ​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PYKqM/